# How to smoothly move WSE web services on Windows 2003 server to the Windows 2008 server?

Tags: wcf, web-services, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

We have WSE web services and now our customer wants all the services available on Windows Server 2008. But Win 2k8 does not support WSE.

What could be quicker and easier solution to this problem? Writing WCF services for each web service is going to be time consuming. Or does anyone on this forum knows solution to it too?

I know this is quite odd question but I want to hear from experts and this would be quite common difficulty people would have faced.

Comment: Why do you think it would be time consuming to rewrite the services using WCF?

Comment: @John : We have services working fine and just because customers are demanding support for Win2k8 we need to take it on priority. Will it not be time consuming to rewrite all the services (more than 25 different web services we have) in WCF? Or is there easier way to do so? I am sorry but I did not get why do you think it would not be time consuming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a large extent, an ASMX or WSE web service looks like the following:

```
[WebService]
public class MyWebService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public ReturnType MyWebOperation(RequestType request)
    {
        // Some code here
    }
}
```

The corresponding WCF service would be:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ReturnType MyWebOperation(RequestType request);
}

public class MyWebService : IMyWebService
{
    public ReturnType MyWebOperation(RequestType request)
    {
        // Same code here
    }
}
```

That assumes, of course, that you don't do anything in the code that is specific to ASMX or WSE.